# Node PassportJS doesn't always authenticate

Tags: node.js, express, authentication, mongoose, passport.js

I am using passport js to authenticate users for my node/express app and it was working fine but recently (I think since adding a custom local strategy but not definitely) passport sometimes doesn't log the user in despite appearing to encounter no issues (success redirect was followed before I removed it as a possible issue and no errors are printed/displayed anywhere). This happens a minority of the time but I cannot work out at all why. The local strategy is not even reached (console.log on the first line doesn't print) when this happens. I have stripped back the login post route to the absolute minimum and the error still happens. It also occurs with twitter login using a different strategy but again the strategy isn't even reached when this happens. Here are the local login routes:

```js
router.get("/login", function(req, res){
    res.render("auth/login");
});



router.post("/login", passport.authenticate("local", {failureRedirect: "/login"}), function(req, res) {
    res.redirect("/");
});
```

I am using bodyparser and have included the rest of the possibly relevant parts of the app.js file below (excluding the twitter strategy for brevity):

```js
// create sessions - SET SECURE TO TRUE IF HTTPS
app.use(session({
    secret: process.env.SESSION_SECRET,
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    cookie: {
        secure: false, //set true if https
        maxAge: 900000 //15 mins without activity
    },
    store: new mongoStore({mongooseConnection: mongoose.connection}),
    rolling: true
}));


// Passport Config
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

passport.use("local", new LocalStrategy(
    {
        usernameField: 'email', //changed the default field that passport looks for in mongo to email
        passwordField: 'password',
        passReqToCallback: true
    }, 
    function(req, email, password, done) {

        //try logging in with username
        User.findOne({ email: email }, async function(err, user) {
            if(err) {
                req.flash("error", "There was an error while communicating with the database");
                console.error(err);
                done(err, null);
            } else {
                
                if (user) {
                    //if user found

                    var auth = await user.authenticate(password);

                    if(auth.user != false) {
                        //if user password is correct
                        done(null, user);
                    } else {
                        //pw incorrect
                        req.flash("error", "Invalid username or password.");
                        done(null, null);
                    }

                } else {
                    //either no user with that email or user logged in with username

                    User.findOne({ username: email }, async function(err, user) {
                        if(err) {
                            req.flash("error", "There was an error while communicating with the database");
                            console.error(err);    
                            done(err, null);
                        } else {

                            if (user) { 
                                 //if user found

                                var auth = await user.authenticate(password);

                                if(auth.user != false) {
                                    //if user password is correct
                                    done(null, user);
                                } else {
                                    //pw incorrect
                                    req.flash("error", "Invalid username or password.");
                                    done(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect username or password.' });
                                }

                            } else {
                                //user not found
                                req.flash("error", "Invalid username or password.");
                                done(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect username or password.' });
                            }
                        } 
                    });
                }
            }
        });
    }
));

passport.serializeUser(User.serializeUser());
passport.deserializeUser(User.deserializeUser());
```

EDIT: I have written a custom callback for the local strategy:

```
router.post("/login", function(req, res, next) {
    passport.authenticate("local", function(err, user, info) {
        if(info) {
            req.flash("error", info.message);
        }

        if(err) {
            req.flash("error", "login error");
            return res.redirect("/login");
        } else if(user) {
            req.login(user, function(err) {
                if(err) {
                    req.flash("error", "login error");
                    return res.redirect("/login");
                }  else {
                    //console.log("req.login ran without throwing an error")
                    return res.redirect("/");
                }
            });
        } else {
            return res.redirect("/login");
        }
    })(req, res, next);
});
```

From this I've discovered that req.login runs even when the bug happens (the user doesn't actually get logged in) so it appears that is the problem. However, I don't know enough about passport and how it works to rewrite it so I still don't know what to do that might fix the issue.

Comment: I'm a fan of explicitly defining my done callback in the passport.authenticate function. Could you try defining something like function(err, user){/* your handling here*/}

Comment: I've written a custom callback which seems to be showing that req.login is the issue. I've updated the post with more details